# SQL Cluster Resources Disappear After Removing Disk Resource

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustering

In the process of removing an usused disk resource from cluster, I would follow these steps: 1) remove dependencies on the disks by the SQL Server resource, 2) take the disk resource offline, 3) delete the disk resource from the SQL resource group, 4) delete the disk resource from the Available storage pool.

I was proceeding to do this on a two node cluster with two SQL 2008 R2 named instances (running Win2K8R2 SP1 build 6701, 64-bit). On deleting a resource in step 3 above, SQL would go offline, all the disk resources would go back to the Available pool, and the SQL resources (Net Name, SQL Server, SQL Server Agent) would disappear. SQL services do restart OK after via the services console as all the disks are still on the same node.

I ran `cluster res` from the command prompt and I see the SQL service resources are still there, in Available Storage, and offline.

To bring the resources back to the appropriate group, can I move them via `cluster` commands?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have almost the same thing. Went to remove a disk from a cluster SQL Server service - and for some reason all disks now show under available storage. The SQL Server service shows no resources. The SQL Server is still up and running. I'm almost afraid to do anything - including run cluster /res... Don't want to lose this production server.

Answer (score 1):

The link below has the likely answer.  Premier Support agrees that the steps to fix should fix my similar issue.  I plan on going through the steps during my next outage window.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/01/14/removing-a-mount-point-disk-from-a-cluster-group.aspx